# A Report Designer for Clients (Dynamic Reports)

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, reportviewer

### I need a report designer for my clients.

My Clients don't know anything about database or DBMS.
They want to have a designer to design their reports.
They want to drag their custom fields in a page and simply design their reports.

I think it is not important but i tell you type of my project is **Windows(winforms) application.**

?????

Someone call this report types as **Dynamic Reports**

Comment: I don't think that is possible to design a report unless you don't know what's going on behind the scene.At least they should now some of the tables that they are going to work with.As far as I know Crystal Report is very suitable for the job because it can work stand alone.You can have some specially designed Views granted to special users and they can use them to do what they want

Comment: Client just know about their input fields and the result they want.

Comment: Maybe your clients don't really want a complex report designer. An alternative could be to let them supply a word document with placeholder-strings that your program replaces when generating reports.

Comment: This is a good idea.but how can i replace placeholder-strings with my database data?

Comment: I know it's possible, but I'd have to google for the exact procedure. There are already some questions about this floating around here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implementing an 'ad hoc' reporting architecture (which is really what you are describing) is not a trivial exercise (nor inexpensive).  However, here are some approaches that you may want to consider:

1. create a number of simple reports that can be exported to Excel. Reports can be grouped and parameterized if necessary, but the key keep the reports in a row-and-column format, with both the dimensional and fact columns.  These reports can be combined in Excel for additional analysis.  Most people have Excel and are fairly familiar with its usage.
2. if budget is less of an issue, consider BusinessObjects' WebIntelligence.  Its drag-and-drop interface for column and filter selection is pretty simple.  Be prepared, however, for a significant investment to purchase license and to develop the semantic layer (the 'Universe') that WebI requires.
3. You may want to shift away from Crystal Report to [Qlikview](http://www.qlikview.com).  Its 'applications' are a bit more flexible that what you can build in CR and allow for some fairly-flexible analysis.  The client is free, but the server license is not.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative package (to Crystal Reports) that has been recommended to me is Dev Express' XtraReports.

http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Reporting/

Unfortunately I haven't used it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your clients don't really want a complex report designer. An alternative could be to let them supply a word document with placeholder-strings that your program replaces when generating reports

Some pointers:

[Create Word 2010 Document Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047782/create-word-2010-document-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

We just started using [QlikView](http://www.qlikview.com/) here at work.  Seems to be able to handle all different types of input data and allows users to configure their reports how ever they want.
I have not used it myself, but a lot of non-developers were in on the initial training class